# Warning: “conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data”

Tags: c, visual-c++

I'm working on my C++ homework about Bitwise Operations: How to use ">>=" (Shift Right) and "<<=" (Shift Left ) operators.

**Input**: Enter two integers N and M (With M is the number of bits).

**Output**: The result of N >>= M and N <<= M.
So this my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    
    /* M is the number of bits
       N is the variable that take the value of ShiftLeft and 
       ShiftRight */

    int N, M;
    double ShiftLeft, ShiftRight;

    printf("Enter integers N: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);

    printf("\nEnter integers M: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &M);

    // You can use: N <<= M OR N * pow(2,M)
    ShiftLeft = N * pow(2,M);    
    printf("\nThe value of N <<= M is: ");
    printf("%lf", ShiftLeft);

    // You can use: N >>= M OR N / pow(2,M)
    ShiftRight = N / pow(2,M);
    printf("\nThe value of N >>= M is: ");
    printf("%lf", ShiftRight);

    (void)_getch();
    return 0;
}
```

After that, these are my tests:

```
Enter integers N: 4
Enter integers M: 2
The value of N <<= M is: 16.000000 
The value of N >>= M is: 1.000000
```

```
Enter integers N: 9
Enter integers M: 12
The value of N <<= M is: 36864. 000000
The value of N >>= M is: 0.002197
```

So now, I want to change my results' data type from `double` into `int`; but, if I change:

```
double ShiftLeft, ShiftRight;
```

into:

```
int ShiftLeft, ShiftRight;
```

the compiler will display an error:

> C4244 '=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data.

or:

> warning C4244:'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int',
> possible loss of data.

I don't know how 0.002197 can change into 0.

I tried replacing all the `double` and `%lf` into `int` and `%d` and I have a result about 0.002197 to 0. But I don't know is this the right way.

Can you give me some advice about the WARNING C4244.

Comment: What are you expecting? If you convert a floating-point number to an integer you lose everything after the decimal point.

Comment: Are you aware that using floating point numbers and the `pow` function arre total overkill for calculating powers of 22? Forget floating point numbers and `pow` for this problem and replace `pow(2, M)` with `1 << M` .

Comment: ... and no, you're not wasting our time. The purpose of this site iss to ask questions aand get them answered.

Answer (score 0):

1. shift right requires `floor`-ing as integers do not fractional part.
   2.You want to print double values, not to scan them:

```
    ShiftLeft = N * pow(2,M);    
    printf("\nThe value of N <<= M is: ");
    scanf_s("%lf", ShiftLeft);
```

it should be

```
    ShiftLeft = N * pow(2,M);    
    printf("\nThe value of N <<= M is: %f\n", ShiftLeft);
```

Whole code:

```
int main(void){
    
    /* M is the number of bits
       N is the variable that take the value of ShiftLeft and 
       ShiftRight */

    int N, M;
    double ShiftLeft, ShiftRight;

    printf("Enter integers N: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    printf("\nEnter integers M: ");
    scanf("%d", &M);

    // You can use: N <<= M OR N * pow(2,M)
    ShiftLeft = N * pow(2,M);    
    printf("\nThe value of N <<= M is: %f\n", ShiftLeft);

    // You can use: N >>= M OR FLOOR(N / pow(2,M))
    ShiftRight = floor(N / pow(2,M));
    printf("\nThe value of N >>= M is: %f\n", ShiftRight);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3cvGfTjfW

Answer (score 0):

`Double` has a mantissa that is 52bit length.  When converting a `double` number into 32bit, part of the bits need to be truncated.  That is the reason of the compiler warning.  If you want to be safe, just operate only with integer types, if you are experimenting with bitwise operators.